# how to receive returned data from a method inside another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, nsmutablearray

I am calling a method from another class, this method returns a NSMutableArray however I am not sure how to receive the returned data from the method...

I call it like this

```
ResultItem *resultItem = [[ResultItem alloc] init];
[resultItem startSortingTheArray:myObjectArray];
```

Then inside the ResultItem class I am setting the method like this

```
- (NSMutableArray *)startSortingTheArray:(NSMutableArray *)unsortedArray
{
//... blaa blaa blaaa then....
return unsortedArray; // how do I capture this value in the other class I called it from?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSMutableArray *)startSortingTheArray:(NSMutableArray *)unsortedArray
```

method provides you an NSMutableArray in return...just store it in a variable!!

```
NSMutableArray *val=[resultItem startSortingTheArray:myObjectArray];
```

Comment: wow.. surprised I didn't know this till now... feel like a who new world of possibilities has opened up.. thanks very much.

Comment: You must go through basics first :) cause the capabilities are limitless and to achive it u should have the floor to stand